# Unique constraint failed - Integrity error - django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Can't find a solution for my probelm online. error message I am receiving regarding problem ----- **IntegrityError at /add_user_address/
UNIQUE constraint failed: users_useraddress.user_id** ------ all help greatly appreciated!

**views.py** 
    import re

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserAddressForm 
from .models import EmailConfirmed


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your registration has been successful! Please check your email to confirm account.')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})

SHA1_RE = re.compile('^[a-f0-9]{40}$')

def activation_view(request, activation_key):
    if SHA1_RE.search(activation_key):
        print("activation key is real")
        try:
            instance = EmailConfirmed.objects.get(activation_key=activation_key)
        except EmailConfirmed.DoesNotExist:
            instance = None
            messages.success(request, f'There was an error with your request.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        if instance is not None and not instance.confirmed:
            page_message = "Confirmation successful, welcome to Fuisce! "
            instance.confirmed = True
            instance.activation_key = "Confirmed"
            instance.save()
        elif instance is not None and instance.confirmed:
            page_message = "Already Confirmed"
        else:
            page_message = ""

        context = {"page_message": page_message}
        return render(request, "users/activation_complete.html", context)
    else:
        raise Http404



@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html')




**def add_user_address(request):
    print(request.GET)  
    try:
        redirect = request.GET.get("redirect")
    except:
        redirect = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserAddressForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            new_address = form.save(commit=False)
            new_address.user = request.user
            new_address.save()
            if redirect is not None:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(str(redirect)))

    else:
        raise Http404**
```

**html file**

```
{% extends "fuisce/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<form method="POST" action='{% url "add_user_address" %}?redirect=checkout'>{% csrf_token %}

{{ address_form.as_p }}

<input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Add Address'/>

</form> 


{% endblock content %}
```

My html and views file are attached, let me know if anything else is needed to solve the problem.

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.urls import reverse

from localflavor.ie.ie_counties import IE_COUNTY_CHOICES

class UserAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150 )
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=IE_COUNTY_CHOICES)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    postalcode = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    shipping = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    billing = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your models file - unique constrain is connected with your model for database. Probably you add for one field in your model attribute "unique=True".

Comment: thanks for reply. I added my models.py file to the bottom of my question is the problem related to 'order_id' as it has a unique=True value?

Comment: No, the problem is with model user, you can see that in error: users_useraddress.user_id. What is in yours models "useraddress" ? it's a field or 'through' table?

Comment: oh my bad, i have edited in my useraddress model into the question. shoud i add in a unique value here?

Comment: User_id is unique as a primary key, don't add anything. Problem is here: user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE). One user can have only one instance of model useradresses. if you have alredy sth in db for that user, you can not save nothing more.